# Pip.exe from Python on Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, windows-10

I installed the latest version of Python from www.python.org.  Python 3.4.3. I then go to run pip and I get

"Fatal error in launcher: Job information querying failed"

Searching for this error message points me to similar issues running Python under wine.  If you grab a pre-compiled pip.exe it will work but it seems that when you install, the pip.exe is generated as part of the installer and this pip.exe does not work.

Further I am dealing with a build script that creates a virtual python environment that uses pip.exe and results in the same error. Not sure how to fix this. Also not sure how pip.exe is generated.

Comment: This is a bug in the current preview release of Windows 10. See the message from Dan Bjorge in [issue 24127](http://bugs.python.org/issue24127). Note that the standalone and simple launcher executables are built as 32-bit applications, so Dan's remark about using "32-bit Python" isn't the problem, but instead that the launcher is 32-bit.

Answer (score 18):

You can use `python -m pip install package`

Comment: I had problems with pip (3.5) in Windows 10, no output from the command, seemed to freeze. This command helped with the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I tried installing a package via pip, but it took forever. Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 2):

Worked for me in windows 10, make sure that you have added python in path of system environment variable. If you are able to run python from powershell then it means python is added to your path. After that you may try using following to upgrade pip

```
python -m pip install -U pip
```